What is $\operatorname{Proj}A[x]$ when $A[x]$ has the trivial grading?
$\newcommand{\Proj}{\operatorname{Proj}}
\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}
\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$
Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $A[x]$ has the trivial grading where every element has degree zero. How can we describe $\Proj A[x]$?
As a set we have that:
\begin{align}
\Proj A[x]=\{\p\in \Spec A[x]:\p\text{ is homogenous and }(A[x])_+\not\subset\p\}
\end{align}
where $(A[x])_+$ is the trivial ideal. However, what is the trivial ideal when we have a trivial grading? If it's the zero ideal, then this set is clearly empty as $\langle 0\rangle\subset\p$ for all $\p$, but that doesn't seem right. If $(A[x])_+$ is just the whole ring for some reason then $\Proj A[x]=\Spec A[x]$.
Also, since every element has degree zero, what are our distinguished opens here? I.e. in the normal Proj construction, we take distinguished open $D_+(f)$ for positive degree elements to be a basis for the topology on $\Proj A[x]$, but here we have not elements of positive degree so what gives?

It is the empty scheme. If $A[x]$ is graded in such a way that all elements have degree zero, then $A[x]_d$ is $A[x]$ when $d=0$ and $0$ otherwise, so $A[x]_+ = \bigoplus_{d>0} A[x]_d = \bigoplus_{d>0} 0 = 0$, and all homogeneous prime ideals of $A[x]$ contain $A[x]_+$ since the zero ideal is contained in any ideal.

Ok, but then if it's the empty scheme how is there a bijection between closed points of $\operatorname{Proj}\mathbb C[x,y,z]$ and $(\mathbb C\cup {\infty})\times \mathbb C$ when $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$ has trivial grading for $x$ variable and usual grading for $y$ and $z$? This was a remark in one of my lectures, and so am confused how both could be true?

If that's what you're concerned about, why did you not put that in your question? It's irritating as an answerer to respond to a question and then get hit with "oh actually I really meant to ask about something else". Anyways, $\Bbb C[x,y,z]$ with the specified grading does not satisfy the hypotheses of your post - not every element is in degree zero, for instance $y,z$ are in degree 1.

I anticipated that I was just misunderstanding something and that it would not be empty, and so this point wouldn't have come up. My apologies for not including it in my question, I just very much thought that it would not be empty. Thank you regardless though.
